# Using Django registration with a Flat UI template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-registration

I have created a template design for signup page using Flat UI. Now i want to use Django registration to register a user. I have goggled various resources but they are very complex and using Django inbuilt form to create a form.

I need simple steps that i can follow

**signup.html**(home/django/mysite/templates)

```
{% extends "base.html" %}


{% block title %}Signup page{% endblock %}


 {% block content %}


  <div class="container" style="width:500px">
  <h3 style="margin-top:100px">Sign Up</h3> 
  <hr>
  <div class="login-form">

    <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="control-group span3" style="width:400px" >
          <input type="text"  value="" placeholder="Enter your name" id="name" style="width:400px;padding-bottom:15px;margin-bottom:10px" >
          <i class="input-icon fui-user" for="login-name"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group span3" style="width:400px" >
          <input type="text"  value="" placeholder="Your E-mail" id="email" style="width:400px;padding-bottom:15px;margin-bottom:10px" >
          <i class="input-icon fui-mail" for="login-name"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group span3" style="width:400px">
          <input type="password" value="" placeholder="Password" id="pass" style="width:400px;padding-bottom:15px;margin-bottom:10px">
          <i class="input-icon fui-lock" for="login-pass"></i>
        </div>


        <div class="control-group span3" style="width:400px">
          <input type="password"  value="" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="login-pass" style="width:400px;padding-bottom:15px;margin-bottom:10px">
          <i class="input-icon fui-lock" for="login-pass"></i>
        </div>

        <div style="text-align:center"> 
        <a class="btn btn-hg btn-primary btn-wide" href="#">Sign Up</a>
        <!--<a class="login-link" href="#">Lost your password ?</a> -->
        </div>
    </form>

  </div><!-- /login-form -->

  </div> <!-- /container -->


 {% endblock content %}
```

**views.py**

```
def signup(request):

  return render(request, 'signup.html')
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',


url(r'^signup/$', views.signup),)
```

What i should write in views.py or models.py to register a user using django registration.

Comment: Are you looking for a tutorial to use django-registration app by ubernostrum?

Comment: No i am asking how i should use my form with django registration instead of using django form like what i should write in views.py /models.py

Comment: You do not have the `name` attribute for any of your fields, so nothing in your form is actually being sent back to the view code.

Comment: The views and models are coded in the same way irrespective of using django provided form or the handmade form as long as you are setting the same form element names and ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use django registration together with custom html/css through django forms. Here are the steps:

1. Provided you have included relevant imports, your `urls.py` looks fine so no changes needed.
2. Create a `forms.py` file in the same folder as your `views.py` and add the following code into `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms

class Signup_form(forms.Form):
    # CSS styles should not be inline. i've moved your style contents under a 'form-control' class
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'text', 'placeholder':'Enter your name', 'id':'name', 'name':'name', 'class' : 'form-control'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Email address", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'text', 'placeholder':'Your E-mail', 'id':'email', 'name':'email', 'class' : 'form-control'}))
    pass1 = forms.CharField(max_length = 20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'password', 'placeholder':'Password', 'id':'pass1', 'name':'pass1', 'class' : 'form-control'}))
    pass2 = forms.CharField(max_length = 20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'password', 'placeholder':'Confirm Password', 'id':'pass2', 'name':'pass2', 'class' : 'form-control'}))
```

3.In your `views.py` file, you have to link pass the Signup_form to your views layer. Change your `views.py` file to the following:

```
from forms import Signup_form

def signup(request):
    form = Signup_form()

    name = request.POST.get('name','')
    email = request.POST.get('email', '')
    pass1 = request.POST.get('pass1', '')
    pass2 = request.POST.get('pass2', '')

    # Do some validations here

    user = User.objects.create_user(name, email, pass2)
    if user:
        user.save()

    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

4.Now that you have passed your Signup_form object in views layer, you can use django template tags to display them in your `signup.html` page. Here's how your `signup.html` could look like:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/custom.css' %}">
{% block title %}Signup page{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container" style="width:500px">
    <h3 style="margin-top:100px">Sign Up</h3> 
    <hr>
    <div class="login-form">

    <form action="" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="control-group span3" style="width:400px" >
            {{ form.name.errors }}
            {{ form.name }}
            <i class="input-icon fui-user" for="login-name"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group span3" style="width:400px" >
        {{ form.email.errors }}
        {{ form.email }}
        <i class="input-icon fui-mail" for="login-name"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group span3" style="width:400px">
        {{ form.pass1.errors }}
        {{ forms.pass2 }}
        <i class="input-icon fui-lock" for="login-pass"></i>
    </div>


    <div class="control-group span3" style="width:400px">
        {{ form.pass2.errors }}
        {{ forms.pass2 }}
        <i class="input-icon fui-lock" for="login-pass"></i>
    </div>

    <div style="text-align:center"> 
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-hg btn-primary btn-wide" value="Sign Up">
        <!--<a class="login-link" href="#">Lost your password ?</a> -->
    </div>
</form>

</div><!-- /login-form -->

</div> <!-- /container -->


{% endblock content %}
```

5.Since i have earlier moved your CSS styles(in point 2) into a 'form-control' class, now we will place it back by adding your styles in a external `custom.css` file. Create a `custom.css` file in the directory static/css/custom.css and add the following into it:

```
.form-control {
width:400px;
padding-bottom:15px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason for creating your own form? Why not inherit it from "django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm" and add an extra field "email"?

Comment: good call anuragal! i think inherit way is more DRY than creating own form too. thks :)

Comment: I realized the `name` attribute is missing in forms.py file. The error results because since there is no `name` in the input fields, views cant use `request.POST.get()` to retrieve data from the form submission. I've since edited forms.py to include `name` attributes. This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your Views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def signup(request):

    username = request.POST.get("name","")
    password = request.POST.get("pass","")
    login_pass = request.POST.get("login-pass","")
    email = request.POST.get("email","")
    if username != "" or password != "" or login_pass != "":
        #do some validations

    user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
    if user:
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
    return render(request, 'signup.html')
```

Above code will register a new user into system

If you would have use Django forms then all the validations will be done by Django.

Note: Please add name attribute to your HTML fields required for getting vaLues in request.POST. Also point your HTMl form action to "signup" view